# Using min-max functions in definition queries of feature services

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service, definition-query

Using a feature service from ArcGIS Online, I would like to display a record wherein one of its attributes is the max of the entire records, but is unable to do so.

If I am using a Feature Class from a geodatabase, I would normally just specify something like this in the definition query:

[image]

The image above will only show records with the smallest and largest numerical value in its "admin id" field, and this works.

However when using a feature service, my challenge is identifying the table name to use. Below is the actual query being tested by me:

[image]

The intention of the above query is to make it show the last record edited. In lieu of the table name, ArcGIS shows a zero (0) instead. I have tried replacing the ? with 0, 1, and the layer name, but they seem to be incorrect.

[image]

The feature service being used was automatically created by ArcGIS Survey123, so there's no MXD for me to apply the definition query on.

Any suggestions on what I can do to do this?

Comment: What if you did create the query within ArcMap, publish it and created a feature service.  Then in Survey123 create a new survey from that existing feature service?

Comment: Thanks Slinddy.

Unfortunately, Survey123 automatically creates the Feature Service for us, so we are unable to modify it before being used.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that subqueries as part of the where clause is not possible in this scenario. ArcGIS Online only allows [standard queries](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/sql-agol.htm).

> ArcGIS Online includes a security configuration option that forces
>   developers to use standardized SQL queries when working with hosted
>   feature layers. This makes it easier for developers and apps to query
>   hosted feature layers and helps prevent SQL injection attacks. The
>   option to allow only standard SQL queries is enabled by default.

Comment: same goes for windowing functions. I tried Edit_Date = Max(Edit_Date) OVER () -- just not supported in the def. query.